# Problem with default Android onKey... sound

Tags: android

I'm having hard time figuring out how to get rid of the default sound played while any key is pressed. I'm using following method but it still plays the same "beep" sound.

```
 @Override public boolean onKeyDown( int keyCode, KeyEvent event )
{
switch ( keyCode )
{
    case 25:
    ChangeImageUP( );
    break;

    case 24:
    ChangeImageDOWN( );
    break;

    default:
    return super.onKeyDown( keyCode, event );
}

return true;
}
```

Please help.

// Update
I have figure out that if I overwrite onKeyUp in my main activity the beep is gone. But when i start a second activity the beep returns, even after using that onKeyUp method.

Answer (score 0):

That is controlled by the operating system and the users settings. You might not be able to modify it..

Comment: I have a webbrowser called Dolphin. It contains similar function but without the beep sound.